# LibGDX Android Gdx.app.exit() doesnt work, how to close app in another way?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, libgdx, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to close template app for android (5 sec after render() method is started).
Application is closing, but activity is alive in backgroung and I can back to app if I want.
When I'm using this.dispose() without timer, right in the end of render() method it works fine - no activity to resume Application, but when gdx draw anything this issue occures.
I've tried put in timer: Gdx.app.exit() / this.dispose() / System.exit(-1) and nothing helps if render() method already working some time.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;
MyGdxGame instance;
boolean isReadyToClose = false;

@Override
public void create () {
    instance = this;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();

    if (!isReadyToClose) {

        isReadyToClose = true;

        new Timer().scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //instance.dispose();
                Gdx.app.exit();

            }
        }, 5);

    }

}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();

    System.exit(-1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't supposed to exit apps on mobile platforms, `Gdx.app.exit` is intended to be used on desktop. Exit on Android works by the user pressing the back key and your application not catching it.